# My EXCEL VBA Script is extremly low, although its short

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, foreach

This is a script I wrote. I run it on a sheet with around 610 Rows, it takes a lot of time until it gives me an output, moreover, I have to wait around 10-15 seconds after each time I change the a value content in this range.

```
Function csvRangeNew(myRange As Range)
Dim csvRangeOutput
Dim entry As Variant
For Each entry In myRange
If Not IsEmpty(entry.Value) Then
    If entry.Value = "New" Then
        If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("wholelist").Range("A" & entry.Row)) Then
            csvRangeOutput = csvRangeOutput & Worksheets("wholelist").Range("A" & entry.Row).Value & ","
         End If
    End If
End If
    Next
    csvRangeNew = Left(csvRangeOutput, Len(csvRangeOutput) - 1)
End Function
```

Basically, what I am trying to do, is that when I set a cell value in Column "B" to "New", it will add it to a comma-separated list.

Comment: your issue is that your literally going to the end of the excel file.

Comment: Are you using this as a worksheet function or purely in code?

Answer (score 1):

As [Doug Coats](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5009293/doug-coats) stated in comments, you are processing every cell in a column. Solution: put `set myRange  = intersect(myRange , myRange.parent.usedrange)` as the first line **inside** the function.

```
Function csvRangeNew(myRange As Range)

    Dim csvRangeOutput
    Dim entry As Variant

    set myRange  = intersect(myRange , myRange.parent.usedrange)

    For Each entry In myRange
    If Not IsEmpty(entry.Value) Then
        If entry.Value = "New" Then
            If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("wholelist").Range("A" & entry.Row)) Then
                csvRangeOutput = csvRangeOutput & Worksheets("wholelist").Range("A" & entry.Row).Value & ","
             End If
        End If
    End If

    Next
    csvRangeNew = Left(csvRangeOutput, Len(csvRangeOutput) - 1)
End Function
```

The Intersect command will truncate down myRange to the used portion of the worksheet.

Comment: DAMMMMM!! that worked like magic. Would you mind elaborate a little bit? I'm new to this EXCEL VBA?

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite work out what your code does (especially why you say you want to track changes in column B but your code references column A) or how it is getting triggered when column B changes.  It seems like you're trying to get the cell range where the word "new" was added and add that range to a comma separated list but ranges are objects so you can't add them to a string.

Here is an approach that assumes you are trying to add the **address** of the cell whose value has been changed to "new" to a comma separated list.  Put this code in the wholelist sheet module.  The comma separated list will be available in the public variable csvRangeNew.

Note that this only works for keeping a running list while changes are being made.  You would need to save the csvRangeNew value somewhere before closing the workbook or recalculate and reset it upon opening the workbook to preserve the existing values.

```
Option Explicit

Public csvRangeNew As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If (Target.Address = "$B:$B") Then 'clearing or deleting column B
        GetCsvRangeNew bClearRange:=True
    ElseIf (Target.Column = 2) Then
        If UCase(Target.Value) = "NEW" Then
           csvRangeNew = GetCsvRangeNew(myRangeAddress:=Target.Address)
        End If
    End If

    Debug.Print csvRangeNew

End Sub

Function GetCsvRangeNew(Optional myRangeAddress As String, _
                        Optional bClearRange As Boolean) As String

    Static csvRangeOutput As String

    If bClearRange Then csvRangeOutput = "": Exit Function

    If (csvRangeOutput = "") Then
        csvRangeOutput = myRangeAddress
    Else
        csvRangeOutput = csvRangeOutput & "," & myRangeAddress
    End If

    GetCsvRangeNew = csvRangeOutput

End Function
```

Comment: The reason I put Column A, is that I wanted to add to the list, all values of rows  in Column A, the their value in column B is "New"